# thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=1, message="Could not connect to ('localhost', 9090)")

Tags: python-3.x, hbase, thrift, happybase

I'm facing Thrift error while connecting to HBase through Python. Please find the error trace below-

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/happybase/pool.py", line 147, in connection
connection.open()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- packages/happybase/connection.py", line 176, in open
self.transport.open()
File "thriftpy/transport/framed/cyframed.pyx", line 113, in thriftpy.transport.framed.cyframed.TCyFramedTransport.open (thriftpy/transport/framed/cyframed.c:2476)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- packages/thriftpy/transport/socket.py", line 104, in open message="Could not connect to %s" % str(addr))
thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=1, message="Could not connect to ('localhost', 9090)")
```

How can I solve this error?

My Hbase configuration looks like this

> - **Python** - 3.6.7
> - **HBase version** - 2.1.2
> - **Happybase version** - 1.1.0
> - **transport** - framed
> - **protocol** - compact
> - **Thrift start command** - ./hbase-daemon.sh start thrift -hsha

Before, I have worked with Hbase versions **1.4.6** and **2.0.1** with same config. I did not face any Thrift error while using **1.4.6**. Can anyone pls guide me to overcome this error in HBase latest version?

Comment: Is thrift server running?

Comment: @NishuTayal Yes, Thrift is running

Comment: is it running on the same port 9090?

Comment: @NishuTayal Yes, Thrift is running is same port 9090. Is it something to do with protocol and transport parameters?

Comment: Did you solved the problem somehow?